# WPF button arrangement

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF, and I am trying to arrange a bunch of buttons:

- I have 5 Marllet buttons: up, down, left, right, reset.
- Arrange up, down, left and right at top, bottom, left and right respectively
- And I want the reset button to take the center position surrounded by other 4 buttons.

Here is my current WPF code, but it lines up the reset button next to other 4, and the other 4 just lined up from top to bottom

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Button Content="Reset" Width="75" Height="30" Click="btnResetCrop3D_Click"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Button FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="20" Content="3" Width="20" Height="30"/>
                                <Button FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="20" Content="4" Width="20" Height="30"/>
                                <Button FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="20" Content="5" Width="20" Height="30"/>
                                <Button FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="20" Content="6" Width="20" Height="30"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
```

I am sorry I don't have enough credits to post an image. So if you have any confusion regarding my description, please let me know.

Comment: You may want to use a `Grid` or `DockPanel` instead of `StackPanel`.

Comment: I would personally suggest that you should use `DockPanel` instead of `Grid`, DockPanel was meant for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JeffRSon said use Grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Left" />
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Top" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Right" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Bottom" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing done with a DockPanel

```
<DockPanel Height="300" Width="300">
    <Button Content="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    <Button Content="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    <Button Content="Left" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    <Button Content="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    <Button Content="Last Child" Height="100" Width="100"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Personal choice, though :)

Comment: Thanks. I choose the one above :)